# Host Site on GitHub, but use different address?

Tags: web, github, server, content-management-system, web-deployment

I want to host my website files on GitHub along with a Git-based CMS such as Forestry or CrafterCMS, but the address of the site is on a different server. Without transferring the URL, how do I connect those files and that URL?

REASONING:
My school has a server, but it is too small to host everything my organization wants to for our site (site and cms). Also, the school server is only updated to php 5.5. The hope is to somehow host the files on GitHub instead, and "push" the presentation of it to the server of the school or have the server of the school somehow "pull" or "redirect to" the GitHub files. Our school can only host static sites, which is all we need, and that is why we hope to use Jekyll, Gatsby, or Hugo, with a Git-Based CMS so that anyone with minimal website/coding experience can maintain the site.

Comment: Will using a custom domain name (instead of the *.github.io default) and hosting the site completely on GitHub suit your purpose?